# pass module parameters from controller to model in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I use the MVC pattern for my NodeJs application.

I have a module called `logger`, it's a customized `console.log` function and I want to access this module in all other modules because I want to log information everywhere.

So my `server.js` requires the logger module. Then it passes this parameter to the controller.

```
const model = require('./model');

module.exports = function(app, logger){

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('main', model.funcOne());
});

};
```

So I want my model having this logger variable.

```
module.exports = {
  funcOne: function(){
    logger.log("msg"); // missing module
    return {
//
    };
  },

  funcTwo: function(){
    logger.log("msg"); // missing module
    return {
//
    };
  }
};
```

Some possibilities:

- I always set the logger variable as a parameter of my model functions
- I require this logger module in each module

Are there any better / cleaner ways?

Comment: Google for aspect-oriented programming in javascript. I'm not too familiar with what is possible in JS but I'm sure there are solutions that are specifically tailored to address cross-cutting-concerns like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what are you looking for, but anyway I'll try to help. You can have a high order function which will wrap your functions with your `logger`.
So how it works - say you want to log every functions you created. But you dont want to refactor all of them and add `console.log() // as example` to all of them. So you created a `withLogger` high order function, like below:

```
const withLogger = (f) => (...params) => {
  console.log('logger')
  return f(...params)
}
```

It takes a function as a input parameter what do you want to log, and returns "same" function with injected `console.log()` in it. It works because of closure, i hope you are familiar with it. So here is an example:

```
const multiply = (x, y) => x * y

const multiplyWithLogger = withLogger(multiply)
const result = multiplyWithLogger(3, 4); // console.log('logger') at this point
console.log(result) // 12
```

You can do same thing with your module, but with more additional steps.

```
// withLogger.js
const logger = require('./mylogger');

const withLogger = (f) => (...params) => {
  logger.log('msg')
  return f(...params)
}

module.export = withLogger;

// your module
const withLogger = require('./withLogger');

module.export = {
  fncOne: withLogger(() => { //do some stuff you want })
  fncTwo: withLogger(() => { //do some stuff you want })
}
```

So every time you call `fncOne` or `fncTwo` you it will log `msg`.

Hope it make sense.